# Scrapy memory leak (concurrency is set to 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, scrapy

I can't figure out why my `scrapy` spider consumes so much memory.

I use `splash` with `scrapy` but `top` shows that it is `python3` which consumes 60% or more memory so I suppose it is not `splash` but scrapy itself.

I've recently added `splash.images_enabled = false` to `lua` script but it doesn't make sense this to increase memory consumption.

So I'm trying to debug it using `telnet`.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, there is almost nothing in RAM.

Do you know where can be the problem?

```
2019-03-29 22:01:55 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scrapy_spider', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 6, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 3, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP': 3, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'LOG_FILE': '/home/fs/sd/logs/scrapy.log', 'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scrapy_spider.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['scrapy_spider.spiders']}


class AutoScrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'autoscrape_spider'

    wait = """
        function main(splash, args)
            splash.images_enabled = false
            splash:set_user_agent(args.ua)
            assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))

            local i=0
            local maxwait=20

            while not splash:select("#odds-data-table .table-container") do
                if i==maxwait then
                    break     --times out at maxwait secs
                end
                i=i+1
                splash:wait(1)      --each loop has duration 1sec
            end
            return { 
                html = splash:html(),
                }
        end
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

- Splash is implemented in Python3 so I would assume it's causing the issue here
- You can try restarting Splash from time to time to avoid using up too much memory (cfr. https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-run-splash-in-production)